# Robust vertical alignment of both box and baseline using line-height?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

When setting the same line-height, height and box-sizing: border-box on elements in a line, I'd expect them to align vertically (both at the baseline and the box) properly.

No luck: alignment seems to always be off by one pixel for some combination of input/span and/or with-border/without-border.

See below or http://jsfiddle.net/xcgyh22q/9/

```css
input, span {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    
    border: none;
    background-color: gray;
   
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    
    width: 40px;
}
input {
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.vmiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}


p {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Two spans</h4>
One span has border - fail...
<p><span>_asd_</span><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
One span has border - fail...
<p><span class="border">_asd_</span><span>_asd_</span></p>
Both spans have border - success
<p><span class="border">_asd_</span><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>

<h4>One input, one span - not the same</h4>
No borders - success
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_"/><span>_asd_</span></p>
span has border - fail...
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_"/><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
input has border - success ...
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border"/><span>_asd_</span></p>
Both elements have border - fail :(
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border"/><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
vertical-align: middle messes up baseline alignment
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border vmiddle"/><span class="border vmiddle">_asd_</span></p>
```

(tested in chrome - seems to vary a bit in other browsers)

Am I missing something obvious or is there no good general solution? I don't want to use padding since that comes with its own set of challenges.

Seems like the pixels above/below the baseline is distributed differently depending on the element type and whether the element has borders. I can understand the mixed-border case, but it's really annoying that input doesn't behave the same way as span. (see span-input, both with borders)

Comment: have you tried when using with box-sizing prefixs?
 *, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: Ignore my comment... fails. This is a weird one indeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your box was too few high.

```css
input, span {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;

    height: 24px; /* Note this correction */
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: gray;
   
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input {
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<h4>One input, one span - the same ;-)</h4>
vertical-align: middle messes up baseline alignment

<p>
  <input value="_asd_" type="text">
  <span>_asd_</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like that at least gives me consistent behavior for elements with border. I guess it can make sense that the content-box need to be big enough for the line-height. Still doesn't explain the cases with border/no-border though.

Comment: Ops... I have studied only this. Just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

In my opinion this code solve your problem. I have simply used a border of the same color of the background.

Thankyou and bye,
*Giacomo*

```css
input, span {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    height: 24px;  /* First correction */
    line-height: 22px;
    
    border: none;
    background-color: gray;
   
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    
    width: 40px;
}
input {
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.border2 {
    border: 1px solid gray; /* Second correction */
}

.vmiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}


p {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Two spans</h4>
One span has border - fail...
<p><span class="border2">_asd_</span><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
One span has border - fail...
<p><span class="border">_asd_</span><span class="border2">_asd_</span></p>
Both spans have border - success
<p><span class="border">_asd_</span><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>

<h4>One input, one span - not the same</h4>
No borders - success
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_"/><span class="border2">_asd_</span></p>
span has border - fail...
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_"/><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
input has border - success ...
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border"/><span class="border2">_asd_</span></p>
Both elements have border - fail :(
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border"/><span class="border">_asd_</span></p>
vertical-align: middle messes up baseline alignment
<p><input type="text" value="_asd_" class="border vmiddle"/><span class="border vmiddle">_asd_</span></p>
```

Comment: Yes that is a pragmatic solution :) (ah - I forgot to accept your answer)

Comment: Do not worry. We are here for finding help and for helping who need, not for to do the first ladies. ;-)